Chrome driver Installation path discrepancy on Windows 11 during bzt run
I'm experiencing an issue with Chromedriver installation during the bzt run.
After downloading a zip file, the system seems to be looking for it in the following path:

15:23:03 ERROR: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\sunimali\.bzt\selenium-taurus\tools\drivers\chromedriver\127.0.6533.73\chromedriver.exe-win64'

However, the actual location of the file is here:

"C:\Users\sunimali.bzt\selenium-taurus\tools\drivers\chromedriver\127.0.6533.73\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"

could you please help me to solve this problem

I am also facing this issue. A bug in the selenium webdriver manager side.
Temporary solution to overcome the issue until they give fix.
Use this below code.
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
            driver_path = driver_path.replace("THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.", "") + ".exe"

It worked for me.
